# how to get theme color programmatically in android java?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to developing with android java. I am trying to set a button's background and textcolor to `colorPrimary` and `colorOnPrimary` values from `/values/themes/themes.xml` so that on dark theme buttons still would look normal.

I need to get these values programmatically i think. `getResources().getColor(R.color.xxx)` method only returns the colors that are set from `/values/colors.xml`

I couldn't find any duplicates of this issue, please read carefully what i'm trying to get. Also, I didn't particularly set my own theme. I adjusted the preset themes. (`themes.xml` and `themes.xml` (night))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of an attribute in your theme you can use something like:

```
val typedValue = TypedValue();
theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValue, true);
val color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, typedValue.resourceId)

button.setBackgroundColor(color)
```

or in java:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorSecondary, typedValue, true);
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, typedValue.resourceId);

button.setBackgroundColor(color);
```